# Kanna setup: blade/mouth width, osae-bo bending

Tags: hand-tools, plane, tool-modification

I'm in the process of setting up my first *kanna*. I'm facing two problems:

1. The blade is wider than the mouth, it overlaps the *mimi* and chips get stuck there (see picture). What is the correct way to remedy this? I would like to avoid grinding the blade to make it narrower.

[image]

2. The *osae-bō* is bending when I hammer the chip-breaker to its proper position. I assume this is problematic. How shall I proceed? Do I need to file down or bend the *mimi* of the chip-breaker?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Most kanna irons that I have seen have their own mimi formed by grinding off the corners so the cutting edge is the same width as the mouth. As it is now the iron is cutting a shaving that is wider than the throat. No wonder it chokes.
2. I see a gap between the pin and the chipbreaker. The gap should be convex and not concave so the pin can exert an even pressure at its centre.

The best source of information I have found is the Craftsmanship in Wood forum on Chris Hall's blog. Find it here http://thecarpentryway.blogspot.ca/

There are some good beginner videos by sumokun on youtube.

Best of luck,
John

Comment: I purchased Chris Hall's e-book on kanna setup. Thanks a lot for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

1. the mouth just has to be opened up. this looks like a manufacturing defect. Chiseling is probably the fastest way, but you can use files or floats.
2. that cross pin is too thin. It's not necessarily a problem, however, if (1) the blade remains fixed in position as desired and (2) shavings don't get stuck under the chip breaker.

Comment: I have straightened the mouth a bit. But it seems like I have to reduce the _mimi_ of the blade nevertheless.

Comment: 1. It is not a manufacturing defect. Do not chisel the mouth wider. The mimi are not fully ground when purchased so you can grind them the way you like. 2. The cross pin is the correct thickness, you must either file the bottoms of the tabs on the chip breaker or hammer the ears flatter to get the proper fit.